# The OPAC display on my library's official website displays an error?

Tags: yii

Good morning,
Please help. The OPAC display on my library's official website displays an error like the following display.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCshI.jpg) or in link perpustkaan.icpasuruan.sch.id/opac

Please help, because I am still a beginner in the world of programming

I've looked for tutorials on YouTube and contacted the developer, I didn't get an answer